# address of file section `.bss' is not within region `ewram' when compiling for Nintendo DS

Tags: homebrew, devkitpro, nintendo-ds

I am compiling a Nintendo DS game, and recently it has been giving me a weird error I've never seen before:

```
.../ld.exe: address 0x2382a18 of .../game.elf section `.data' is not within region `ewram'
.../ld.exe: .../game.elf section `.itcm' will not fit in region `ewram'
.../ld.exe: .../game.elf section `.bss' is not within region `ewram'
.../ld.exe: .../game.elf section `.data' is not within region `ewram'
.../ld.exe: .../game.elf section `.bss' is not within region `ewram'
.../ld.exe: region `ewram' overflowed by 22960 bytes
```

How do i fix it?

Edit: I redownloaded the source code and it magically works?

Edit 2: Yes, it's because too much stuff was in the executable.

Comment: Seems like there was too much data (global variables) to fit in the DS's memory

Comment: ok i fixed it... it was because all game sounds were loaded at once